# Order By SQL Server PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I would like order the result of my select ids starting with 16, 15 and 17.
How could I do this?
My Select:

```
SELECT id_t_produtos
FROM table 
ORDER BY nullif(id_t_produtos, 16) ASC
```

The expected response:

```
- 16
- 15
- 17
- 1
- 2
- 3 ...
```

Comment: 16 / 15 / 17 or 15 / 16 / 17 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, I would do something like this

```
select ids from table
order by 
  case ids when 16 then 0 
           when 15 then 1
           when 17 then 2
           else 3
  end, 
  ids
```

replace `ids` by `id_t_produtos` if that's the ordering field, not really clear...

Comment: SELECT ids 
FROM table 
ORDER BY case when ids 18,16 then 0 else 1 end, ids ?

Comment: @Mourinha edited for 16 15 17. With 10, 15, 5 you will get 15, 5, 10

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ids 
FROM table 
ORDER BY CASE id_t_produtos
      WHEN 16 THEN 1
      WHEN 15 THEN 2
      WHEN 17 THEN 3
      WHEN 1  THEN 4
      WHEN 2  THEN 5
      WHEN 3  THEN 6
     ELSE 7 END ASC, id_t_produtos ASC
```